# PHP store foreach query results in array in specific format

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to store the results of a query in an arrow, but need to do so in a specific format (I think).

The required format I need the results to be in is as follows:

```
'screenshots' => 'Plugin Screenshots',
```

This is what I have so far, along with my failed attempt to store the results:

```
$my_fake_pages = array();

$args = array(
    'parent' => 8,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $my_fake_pages[] = $category->slug . '=>' . $category->slug;
}
```

What troubles me most is I do not understand how I would go about getting the `=>` in there, as without the inverted commas dreamweaver throws up PHP errors.

This is what it would look like normally:

```
$my_fake_pages = array(
    'installation' => 'Plugin Installation',
    'usage' => 'Plugin Usage',
    'screenshots' => 'Plugin Screenshots',
    'changelog' => 'Plugin Changelog',
    'feedbacks' => 'Users\' Feedbacks',
);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $my_fake_pages[$category->slug] = $category->slug;
}

print_r($my_fake_pages);
```

Comment: This seems to display the values in the format `[advertising] => Advertising`. I need to lose the square brackets and insert inverted commas around each word. How is this done?

Comment: @CoreyRS I think you are confused. `print_r` is just a string representation of the variable. In the following: `$myarray = array('installation' => 'Plugin Installation'); $myarray2 = array(); $myarray2['installation']='Plugin Installation';` The 2 arrays are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The notation `'something' => 'another thing'` means it's a key/value pair. So all you need to do is change your assignment line to something like `$my_fake_pages[$category->slug] = $category->name`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.examples

Comment: This seems to display the values in the format `[advertising] => Advertising`. I need to lose the square brackets and insert inverted commas around each word. How is this done?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your array contains the value 'Advertising' under the key 'advertising'. It's the same thing as if you declared it right in the start `$my_fake_pages = array('advertising' => 'Advertising');`. If all you want is to display your array in that particular format, you could just iterate over the array and display your key/value pairs `foreach($my_fake_pages as $key => $value) { echo "'$key' => '$value'"}`

Comment: Ah, I see! I shall give this a whirl and see how it goes.